# How to validate Width and Height of image in model of cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp

I want to check width and height and allow only 900x700  size image in cakephp, also want to apply format type validation. I want to do this using model validation I'm new to cakephp, please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For Image type validateion there is core rule available in Cakephp.

Ex:

```
public $validate = array(
'image' => array(
    'type' => array(
        'rule'    => array('extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
    ),
    'size' => array(
        'rule'    => array('validateImageSize'),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
    )
);


public function validateImageSize() {
      //Check Image dimension here
}
```

For Image Size validation you can check in custom rule.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanx pankaj it helps me a lot.